# Clone a DAC to insert a new DAC

Tags: acumatica

How to create a copy of a DAC (i.e. cloning it) in Acumatica Framework. I can of course create a new instance and set all the value individually but is there a method which does this for you?

I found the following method

```
PXCache<...>.CreateCopy(sourceRule);
```

However, this seems to copy everything, including the ID, CreatedBy etc.
I would need a **new** DAC, with all relevant fields copied.
How to do this please?

Comment: After researching PXCache<T> class I can say that Acumatica's PXCache.CreateCopy and PXCache.RestoreCopy are copying all the fields that DACs have. So you probably will have to write the Copy function by yourself.

Comment: I think I managed to get it working by using CreateCopy and then just setting the ID to null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PXCache` `CreateCopy` to perform the copy like you mentioned, then null/change the keys before inserting the new copy into the cache.

Here is an example that will copy a sales line as a new line on a sale order extension:

```
var soLine = PXCache<SOLine>.CreateCopy(Base.Transactions.Current);
// Null the keys of SOLine
soLine.OrderType = null;
soLine.OrderNbr = null;
soLine.LineNbr = null;
Base.Transactions.Insert(soLine);
```